# finding general solutions of second order diffrential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find the general solution of

$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} +9y =18$$

I am not sure how to write it in its complementary form because of the roots one being positive and the other negative

Comment: The general solution is $c_1e^{r_1t} + c_2e^{r_2t}$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. The roots being positive or negative doesn't change anything.

Comment: The particular solution is $y=2$.

Comment: I don't understand can you give me some more help

Comment: Note that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(y-2)+9(y-2)=0$ - can you solve this?

Comment: as in implicit?

Answer (score 0):

Take Laplace Transform, $(s^2+9)Y(s) - c_1 s - c_2 = \frac{18}{s}$

Thus, $Y(s) =  \frac{18}{s(s^2+9)} + c_1 \frac{s}{s^2+9} + c_2\frac{1}{s^2+9} = 2\frac{s^2+9-s^2}{s(s^2+9)}+ c_1 \frac{s}{s^2+9} + c_2\frac{1}{s^2+9} = \frac{2}{s} + (c_1-2) \frac{s}{s^2+9} + c_2\frac{1}{s^2+9}$.

Now, do an inverse Laplace transform. 
$y(x) = 2 + (c_1-2) cos(3x) + \frac{c_2}{3} sin(3x)$, where $c_1 = y(0)$, and $c_2 = y'(0)$

Answer (score 0):

The auxiliary equation is $m^2 +9=0$ $\implies$ $m=\pm\iota 3$ $\implies$ $c_1cos(3x)+c_2sin(3x)$ as a general solution. Now you have to find the Particular solution for the problem. The sum of both solutions is the complete solution.